# Creating a function where I clear every position in a 2-D array and making it the default '_'character cell

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

I am creating a program that implements a tic-tac-toe game using a 2-D array with multiple functions. How would I create a function where it clears all 'x' and 'o' characters in each cell and have the cells reset it back to the underscore character '_'? An example along with your explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any code of what you have tried to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `memset` to reset the array to `_` as below.

```
char array[10][10];
memset(array, '_',  sizeof(array));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use memset that's the way you need to take, it's fast and safe. ([view the answer of @Kiran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53040595/9814037)).

*But I will explain you something.*

### If you are interested about, how do it works at **back end** you can reproduce it **yourself** ?

---

*Introduction -->*

You can make all functions of *standard lib* just for your **personal** **understanding**.You can make your own lib which does nothing more, nothing less than the libs with prefix "my" on each functions. That's better to understand more than just reading the documentation sometimes, but each person have not this *kind of mind*. I assure that I never said that one of these methods is better than anothers, just sometimes it's better for **yourself**. I accepted all methods during my experiences because sometimes you need one and another time you need another one.

---

*Solution -->*

```
lenght_array_2D(char **2D_array)  // A func which will return the length of your array
{
   int i = 0;

   if (!2D_array)
      return (0);

   for (; 2D_array[i] ; i++) {
      //todo something such as debug log.
   }
   return (i);
}

[...]

int y = lenght_array_2D(your_2Darray);
    while (i < y) {  // walk into your array
      for (int j = 0 ; array[i][j] ; j++) { //check on each line if you have the pattern asked
        if (array[i][j] == 'x' || array[i][j] == 'o')
            array[i][j] = '_'; // if it is, you can replace it.
      }
       i++;
    }
```

Try to understand the back end of a function do you use it's good for your own understanding and your experiences.

I hope that you have understood well, in the long run you will use **memset** and few another functions which does it  for you, but make sure that you have understood what they're doing in the back.

Best regards dude!

Comment: Any specific reason you mix `while` and `for` loops?

Comment: @alk No, I have specified in my answer that was just a way to understand "how to do this". We can optimize that. You can walk into an array with a for and while loops, it's not a problem, you have a lot of articles which speaks about when you must use "for" or "while" but note that both works!

Comment: The snippet misses the break condition for `i`. `while(array[i++])` sooner or later invokes undefined behaviour by reading beyond `array`'s bounds.

Comment: Yes, but again, it was just an example to show the way, I don't answer to his question with a good way because it's too easy, if I guide it to the best way,  it's better than copy and past for him. Last one, I've specified: `my code may can doesn't work` Because if he copy --> and --> paste he will don't understand at all how it works.

Hmm, i am new on Stack and i want to help each others, then I understand what are you seeing and i will edit my post Dude.
Regards.

Comment: `my code may can doesn't work` In that case you should not have answered.

Comment: @kiranBiradar No problem but i changed my answer, he will learn not more with a simple copy and paste :)

Good luck to him.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation within the code, it really helped me understand it.

Comment: How would I check if there was three in a row of either 'x' or 'o'?

Comment: would I also declare 'x' and 'o' as a type char?

Comment: @alk && kiranBiradar I understand your opinion about my first answered and I understand that she can mislead, then I changed it and we can see that PhilipPenalber understand and he's curious about "how to". I don't really merit a negative vote on my answer.

Comment: @PhilippPenalber You can check it with another function like :

`If case actual and case +1 and case + 2 == 'x'` then you can do something;

Note:
You have multi method to implement this in your code, think that you have an 2D ARRAY, you can check the next case and next->next case.

Open Another post if you have don't understand because that's not the topic conversation.